# Is this code a thread-safe way to add and remove items from a vector?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to understand thread-safe well, so, I have a simple code (code isn't real) that I have applied thread-safe as follow:

```
vector<int> myList;
const unsigned short ListSize = 5;
mutex mut;
condition_variable cond;

void AddItem() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ListSize + 2; i++) {
        mut.lock();
        myList.push_back(i);
        mut.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
        cout << "An item added." << "\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
    }
}

void RemoveItem() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mut);
        cond.wait(locker, []() { return !myList.empty(); });
        myList.erase(myList.begin());
        cout << "An item removed." << "\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
    }
}


int main() {

    thread th_task1(&AddItem);
    thread th_task2(&RemoveItem);
    th_task1.join();
    th_task2.join();

    if (!myList.empty()) {
        cout << "There are " << myList.size() << " items." << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << "The list is empty." << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can test the code from [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJ2UkI8Lv).

**Is that code considered thread-safe? if not how to make it thread-safe?**

Comment: Random thoughts. There is an extra lock contention on the cout that could influence performance. The loop might be far too short running to show problems. Sleep while holding the lock simulate large work, is that what you want to test? The time to create a thread is not inconsequential, you might want to start with mut locked and unlock it after both threads are created. Is there any fairness in who gets to take a mutex?

Comment: @Surt: Thank you for your thoughts. Regarding using `std::cout` and sleep they are just for testing. (1) Is it a good way to start the function with locked `mut` and unlock it at the end of the function, or I must lock/unlock just the part that adding/removing items? (2) When using the input/output streaming (`std::cin`, `std::cout`) is it required to use the lock/unlock with them too?

Answer (score 1):

It's thread-safe (as in, you lock when you should, and do `wait` properly), but it's not a very good use of threads, because you only notify the remove thread when the add thread has completely finished.

So you may as well just call `AddItem()` and then `RemoveItem()` directly from `main`.

Also, though I recognise the sleeps are just for experimenting, you probably want to consider bringing those sleeps *out* of the locks because otherwise, again, you're just creating lots of contention that stops the multi-threading from being in any way useful.

Comment: Regard to taking the sleep process out of locks, when I do, there is a removal operation that takes place right after the first addition operation, although it has to perform all the adding operations first and then the removal operations. I don't know why this happened? look at this [screenShot](https://i.ibb.co/ncQry3G/screen-Shot.jpg)

Comment: @LionKing _"it has to perform all the adding operations first and then the removal operations"_ Then why are you using two threads? This is not what threads are for. If you want to do thing A, then thing B... just do that. Threading does not help you here. _"I don't know why this happened?"_ Because that's what threading does!!! It makes things happen _concurrently_.

Comment: Honestly, why are you using threads when you don't even know what they are?

Comment: As I said before "I am trying to understand thread-safe well". But you're right, the implementation method for this example should be adding an item then remove an item and not add all items then remove all items.